# HTML and CSS Dropdown Box with Textbox beside it

Tags: jquery, html, css, dropdownbox

I'm having a little bit of trouble, I am trying to make a dropdown box which joins with a text box beside it. I have looked everywhere I can and cant manage to find something like this. It has to look like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: this may help [Amazon Style Search Box using jQuery & CSS](http://w3lessons.info/2013/08/08/amazon-style-search-box-using-jquery-css/)

Comment: Since the question is closed, I couldn't share my contribution. If anyone needs, I have created a gist for you. https://gist.github.com/vigneshrajarr/4a89d6428e723cdcfb7433a0f4c756f3

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```css
select,
input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
select {
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-right: 0;
}
input {
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
</select><input type="text" />
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the result, I had did something similar to this yesterday but the top and bottom right edges border of the select box need to be sharp so it looks like it is as one. Is there any way of getting this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select><input type="text">
```